# Password validation in nodejs using passport js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I'm using passport js local strategy for authentication and nodejs. problem is when i try to login with wrong password, I still redirects to success page.

what i have to do

this is login strategy

```
 const passport = require('passport')
 const LocalStratery = require('passport-local').Strategy;

 const User = require('../models/userAuth')

 passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
 });

 // used to deserialize the user
 passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
   User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});

passport.use('local-login', new LocalStratery({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password',
  passReqToCallback: true
   }, function(req, email, password, done) {
     console.log(email)
     console.log(password)
      User.findOne({email: email})
     .then((err, user) => {
       if(err) {
        return done(null, err, req.flash('unkonown', 'there was an error, 
    please try after sometime'))
     } 
      if(!user) {
           console.log(user)
           return done(null, false, req.flash('NotExists', 'no user 
         exixts'))
       }
        if(!user.validpass(password)){
             return done(null, false, req.flash('passFail', 'password not 
       matches'))
       }
          if(user) {
            return done(null, user, req.flash('success', 'login success'))
        }
      }) 
      .catch(err => {
       throw err
     }) 
   }))
```

user model using mongoose

```
  userAuth.methods.excryptPass = function(password) {
     return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(5), null)
 }
 userAuth.methods.validpass = (password) => {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
  }
```

Comment: what is this.password? Are you sure that is the password from the db?

Comment: yae,, i declare it in my mongoose model in same file where my validpass method resides.

Comment: Ok and the user object that gets returned from User.findOne - does that object have the validpass method? I'm just asking cause I cant see how user.validpass and userAuth.methods.validpass is wired together?

Comment: I think , the returned user object from findOne() treats authUser.validpass() as a method to check or compare the password. Is it correct or i can explicilty declare a method for user object that returned from findOne()..If not how to access the authuser.validpass from mongoose model to validate password.